# Trends in size of computer programs

Tags: reference-request, compilers, software-engineering

Everyone knows code bloat is a real thing, of course.

Everyone knows that programs are getting bigger too (this may be nothing to do with 'bloat' of course - they are more sophisticated, safer or faster even: maybe).

So why can't I find any papers on Google Scholar or in the ACM Library that back up either claim?

Happy to be guided to good search terms because if the papers exist then my searching is poor. My particular interest is in real-time/embedded software but general discussions of the issue are also useful.

Comment: Maybe because human nature is rarely an item of study in computer science?

Comment: Why is the size and sophistication of programs solely a matter of human nature? I can assure you it matters in operating system design and memory management - if you have to pull more code over a steep memory hierarchy for instance.

Comment: There is a [talk by Jonathon Blow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k56wra39lwA) where he laments the number of engineers at Twitter to do what is at its core a really simple thing.

Comment: Look for "Wirth's law" and similar ones

Comment: What is your agenda, that program sizes grow faster than the feature sets? That's mostly due to cost/benefit concerns, I imagine. Space issues are still there for some real-time/embedded platforms, but in general most programmers no longer need to obsess about saving a few bits, bytes, or CPU cycles. That's largely a good thing, IMHO.

Comment: No, I want to show that even embedded and real-time programmers need to deal with ever bigger memory demands.